# What to do with bubbles under touchscreen?

Tags: display, hardware-failure

I've been using this computer for nearly 4 years and now it has this bubble under the touchscreen and is still expanding. Both the display and the touchscreen works fine and it doesn't bother me much if I'm not watching videos in full screen.

[image]

Before possibly causing more damage, I'm here to ask, is it even possible to fix this without replacing the screen? Or should I just wait it to expand to the whole screen? Or is there anything I could do to stop it from expanding? I see nothing wrong in the affected area except for the black boundary, and the slightly darker color (maybe higher reflection) as shown in the picture. But does it have any other bad effects?

Comment: There are vacuum autoclaves that can repair a cellphone sized screen, but I'm not aware of equipment for a tablet or laptop. There are online links showing experiments using an iron, and other methods. They have varying success and longevity, and risk making it worse or damaging other things (and generally don't permanently restore it to original condition). If you would otherwise toss it, it might be worth experimenting. The real solution, though is to replace the screen. Weigh the cost on a 4 yr old computer vs. putting that toward a replacement computer with all new parts and a warranty.

Comment: The first thing I care is not to risk destroying the display and/or the touchscreen functionality. If the display no longer works I could probably only throw away the entire computer. But some visual defects are expected considering it is 4 yr old. Fixing or making it fully expand is better if it doesn't risk more damage.

Comment: So it requires a vacuum autoclave and it's a better idea to ask repair shops directly about whether it can be fixed. But I still have questions about the consequences of fixing it or leaving it as is.

Comment: There's also lots of variables in the defect, so there isn't a one-size-fits-all answer.  If the bubble is at an edge, you might be able to work it to the external hole, maybe with the help of a small vacuum pump if you can seal it to the edge, use some heat and pressure to try to get the layers re-adhered, and use something to seal the edge.  The temperature would depend on the specific construction of the display, and you would probably have to remove the display to do a decent job and not damage other things.  Still, you could destroy the display.

Comment: You would need to do some online research to find solutions to defects similar to yours and decide what you're comfortable attempting.  If the screen is still usable, I probably wouldn't mess with it.  There is a decent risk of making it worse or unusable; repair might improve it, but rarely returns it to original condition, and the repair may not last.  BTW, no shop would try to repair the bubble, they would replace the screen.