# What happened to this screen?

Tags: display, hardware-failure

[image]
[image]

So I did nothing after [the previous problem](https://superuser.com/q/1106389/438289). After a few days this happens. Still, the display and touchscreen works fine. I guess this is less fixable than the previous problem. But what even is this? Say, is there a name for this problem or the responsible component? What happened there? Is it likely going to fail soon?

Comment: It is expanding quickly and is twice as big now...

Answer (score 1):

It looks a lot like layers have separated. I've seen grey feathery spots on screens before from the LED being damaged, but this looks a *lot* like dust getting in between the digitiser and screen, rather than pixels being damaged.

You could see if there's a FRU for the screen and/or digitiser for this model.

If you're feeling *particularly* brave, I know of folks who separated the screen and digitiser on *phones*, used UV sensitive transparent glue of some sort and fixed it.

So, you're looking for a screen, or a screen + digitiser. The exact model should be in a service manual, or simply read off the markings.

I don't think there's a chance of imminent failure, but boy would it be annoying.

Comment: The pixels display all colors fine. I'm more worried about the white curve than the feathery part. What is an FRU? And I don't think anyone is still manufacturing screens for this model...

Comment: FRU=Field Replaceable Unit....https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-replaceable_unit

Comment: If it's the layers being separated, the bubble on the top of the left image should be layers separated too. So, are they separating different pair of layers?

Comment: if the digitizer is peeling off, it might result in an effect like that.  In *theory* you could **Very carefully*** peel and clean up the digitizer and screen and possibly glue it back on with LOCA glue. My guess would be the digitizer and screen assembly are seperating here.